# HTML standards for "in-page" navigation

Tags: html

I was wondering, is there any (hidden) standard for navigation within a web page?
What I mean is, we all know that many, many pages have a search box (powered by Google, Bing or custom) for searching within the site. Is there a keyboard shortcut standard for accessing directly to the search box? In addition, usually when results are returned to the client, the user has to page through the results. Is there standard for paging results too? you know, it can be very convenient to be able to go to the next result set, previous, first, last... or perhaps even a specific page number in the result set. Is this feasible at all to go into a standard?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a keyboard shortcut standard for accessing directly to the search box?

No, just [accesskey](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey), which has [drawbacks](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#poor).

> Is there standard for paging results too?

Just conventions, such as Yahoo!'s [Search Pagination Pattern](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/navigation/pagination/search.html)

> it can be very convenient to be able to go to the next result set, previous, first, last... or perhaps even a specific page number in the result set

The [rel attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel), specifically [the start, next and prev values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-links)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a special  tag for navigation elements.

Look at:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make my self clear.
What i meant was standards for the end user, which will make all the sites uniform. Meaning that I, as a web surfer, always know that if i want to make a search on any site, i press for example Alt+Shift+S and i get to the search box. I was not talking about the web programmer, which might implement such an access key differently than some other programmer. He might even do it differently himself on several sites. So, sorry for the confusion and thanks for your time!